# How to find fully paid orders in Shopware 6? (are partial payments possible?)

Tags: shopware, shopware6

What is the right way to find full-paid orders in Shopware 6?

We are using this code:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->addFilter(new EqualsFilter('transactions.stateMachineState.technical_name', 'paid'));

...

$this->orderRepository->search($criteria, $context)->getEntities()
```

This seems to work in general. But what if an order has multiple transactions? I believe this would find still partially paid transactions.

Can an orders even have multiple transactions? How would that case be created in the frontend?

Comment: Technically it is possible to have multiple transactions per order. But this case is not yet implemented in the storefront. It's a preparation for the future, when maybe using gift-cards or similar things. But nothing yet planned, just a preparation to have less breaks when implementing such things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a status called `paid_partially`, so they would not be part of the `paid` status. Partial payment are possible, just like partial shipping & refunding. However, as far as I know, on the frontend, there is no default payment method that can do partial payments. You will need to find a suitable plugin for this to work on the frontend.